# Can the judiciary "legalize" something?

Tags: legal-concepts, legal-terms

The headline for an [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/24/world/asia/taiwan-same-sex-marriage-court.html) in today's New York Times reads: "*Court Ruling Could Make Taiwan First Place in Asia to Legalize Gay Marriage*"

My question is whether this can truly be considered "legalization." This seems to be the case based on the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legalize) of the word:

> to make legal; especially :  to give legal validity or sanction to

But for some reason I have the feeling that only those with legislative power (rather than interpretive power) can truly "legalize" something. I would argue (not very confidently) that if a court decides that something is legal based on interpretation of the *currently existing* laws, than that thing in some sense has *always* been legal. I think I'm wrong about this, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newspapers often say things that are not technically true by the standards of legal usage, especially in headlines which must be brief. "Legalize" is a popular or political concept, not a legal one. Instead, the legal concept underlying such court actions is that (1) an existing prohibition is unconstitutional, and thus such a law cannot exist, and (2) anything is legal unless it is specifically made illegal. "Legalize" is a reasonable term that describes what happens in such cases: to make something be legal (per (2) that means "remove a restriction").